# Simple User Registration & Login Script in PHP and MySQLi

Tags: php, authentication

Hello I use the code below for my login system and I was wondering if someone can help me I'm trying to add an admin features so it will show a link saying admin and if there not an admin then it will disable the link.

http://www.allphptricks.com/simple-user-registration-login-script-in-php-and-mysqli/

Comment: instead of creating a link, just get the username and if that username is an admin, then you show that user specific information that the normal user wouldnt see.

Comment: i have been trying for awhile but still cant get it to work with the code

Answer (score 0):

Make database field something like `user_role` or name it however you want but use it to store user role/privilege.
After user is logged in store data from that field to session and perform conditional check.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_role'] && $_SESSION['user_role'] === 'admin')
{
    // user have admin privilege
}
```

Create function for sake of reusability.

```
function isAdmin()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_role'] && $_SESSION['user_role'] === 'admin')
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
if (isAdmin()) {
    echo 'You are admin!';
}
```

This is just example, name your session and function however you want.

Best regards.

Answer (score -1):

After the login the username is stored in `$_SESSION['username']`. 
So I think something like this should do the trick:

```
if ($_SESSION['username'] === 'admin') {
   echo '<a href="...">admin</a>';
} else {
   echo 'admin';
}
```

When you have an extra field in your user table, lets call it 'group', and this field is filled with the group name 'admin' you can fill this group name in the session at this point of the login script:

```
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($rows==1){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['group'] = $row['group'];
    // Redirect user to index.php
    header("Location: index.php");
}'
```

and later in the code check the session with `$_SESSION['group']` instead of `$_SESSION['username']`, like above.

Comment: i have a field in database called status would that work?

Comment: I think the code above should be enough. Does it not work?
What is the error?

Comment: It does work but It will only work with users that are called admin I need it so I can use a different field and k can set to admin or member pls?.

Comment: @Gesundheitsminister bad example, you are telling OP to store username to session and only username would be admin. That's bad, I will write my answer.

Comment: @AleksaArsić the example is not how I would do it. It bears reference to the login script the OP uses (http://www.allphptricks.com/simple-user-registration-login-script-in-php-and-mysqli/). A full rewrite would be out of the scope.

Comment: I have tried the code above no errors 

`<?php

include("auth.php");

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Welcome Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="form">
<p>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>!</p>

<?php

    if ($_SESSION['user_role'] === 'Admin') {
        echo 'Admin';
    } else {
        echo 'Normal User';
    }

?>

<p>This is secure area.</p><br>
<p><a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a></p>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Looks good to me. So it works as expected? If you need to know if the session is filled correctly you can print it out with `print_r($_SESSION);`